# memory leak in weblogic rmi driver

Tags: weblogic, datasource, jndi, rmi, weblogic-10.x

We are having a memory leak  issue after we started to use our existing Weblogic Datasource from our standalone apps. Standalone apps and WL Datasource does not lay in the same server. We are retrieving datasource with JNDI via t3 protocol.

We have used the approach down here.
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs51/classdocs/API_jndi.html

87% of heap is allocated with `weblogic/jdbc/rmi/internal/StructImpl_oracle_sql_STRUCT` objects. This objects are in package RMI(Remote Method Invocation) and the problem itself started to appear after this remote usage. Since these two things happened at the same time we are suspicious that if we have done something wrong in the process of remote Datasource usage.

Everything works fine but we are restarting the nodes every 2-3 days and started to became a burden to us.

What can be the causes of this memory leak? Should we change anything in datasource properties or do we need to pass extra JVM parameters?

Here is a snapshot of our heap

[image]

Here is the weblogic properties.

```
Weblogic major version 10.3.6.0 
Patch level: 10.3.6.0.181016 (October 2018 PSU - GENM)
Java version: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.45-b01, mixed mode) - 1.6.0_45
MEM_ARGS="-Xms4096m -Xmx6144m -Xmn1024m -XX:SurvivorRatio=8 -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:PermSize=256m -XX:MaxPermSi
ze=512m -verbosegc -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -XX:+PrintGCDetails -Xloggc:${LOGDIR}/GC_logs.${SERVER_NAME} -XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation -XX
:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=100 -XX:GCLogFileSize=512M"
--- EXTRA JAVA OPTIONS
-DASA_MARK=ASA_VERSION_2016.02.17"
-Dweblogic.management.server=${ADMIN_URL}"
-DHostName_WLSName=${value_hostname}-${WLS_NAME}"
-Dweblogic.system.BootIdentityFile=${DOMAIN_HOME}/boot.properties"
-Dweblogic.rjvm.enableprotocolswitch=true"
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true"
```

Here is our standalone app properties

```
[wlsadmin@machine1 cfg]$ /usr/java/jdk1.6.0_26/bin/java -version
java version "1.6.0_26"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_26-b03)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.1-b02, mixed mode)
CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:$HOME/lib/wlfullclient.jar
[wlsadmin@machine1 META-INF]$ more MANIFEST.MF 
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Implementation-Vendor: Oracle Corp.
Implementation-Title: JDK 1.6 Client jar for WebLogic Server 10.3  Tue
  Nov 15 08:52:36 PST 2011 1441050 
Implementation-Version: 10.3.6.0
CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:$HOME/lib/ojdbc5.jar
[wlsadmin@machine1 META-INF]$ more MANIFEST.MF 
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Specification-Title: "Oracle Globalization Development Kit"
Class-Path: orai18n-mapping.jar orai18n-utility.jar orai18n-collation.
jar orai18n-translation.jar orai18n-net.jar orai18n-servlet.jar orai1
8n-lcsd.jar orai18n-tools.jar gdk_custom.jar
Created-By: 1.5.0_07 (Sun Microsystems Inc.)
Main-Class: oracle.i18n.util.GDKOracleMetaData
Implementation-Title: "orai18n.jar archives"
Specification-Vendor: "Oracle Corporation"
Specification-Version: "Oracle Globalization Development Kit - 11.2.0.
1.0 - Production, Build : 11"
Implementation-Version: "Oracle Globalization Development Kit - 

-Xms64m -Xmx256m
```

Comment: Did you check that your code is correctly closing result sets, statements and connections ?
One more thing, don't forget this feature is deprecated and will be disabled in the next version of WebLogic.

Comment: @EmmanuelCollin Yes I have checked all but I saw nothing suspicious about them. They are all well closed. I also monitored Datasource from weblogic admin console and I saw there is no connection leak.I have heard it will be out of support but since this is a legacy system we can keep on this weblogic version for at least 5 years...

Comment: Are you sure this is a memory leak and not just a big resultset loaded from the database ? Do you have any heap metrics to confirm the memory leak ?

Comment: Have a look at the advanced properties on the Weblogic Data Source i.e. "Wrap Data Types" . If it is enabled then switch it off and see do you get performance improvements ..

Comment: @EmmanuelCollin what kind of metric? We are sure it is not because of result-set

Comment: @mkane we already tried that too before but did'nt help :(

Comment: First, activate the jdbc connection profiling in weblogic to confirm (or not) any connection leak.
Second, setup GC logs in your client application to confirm (or not) a memory leak

Comment: @EmmanuelCollin memory leak is on weblogic side not client.

Comment: https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/PatchDetail?requestId=16498880&_afrLoop=180495981027573&patchId=11786853&languageId=0&platformId=2000&_afrWindowMode=0&_adf.ctrl-state=155z2l96rz_66

I found this patch but since my version is 10.3.6  it is not applicable. Can i assume that this patch is already included in 10.3.6?

Comment: The bug note says it is corrected in 12.1.1.0.0.  
Are you sure you are facing the same memory leak ? If you have a support account open a SR.
The support may reject your SR because you are using an out of date version of java (1.6 is no longer supported since december 2018)

Comment: @EmmanuelCollin I checked the fixed bug list of 10.3.6 and I saw this bug there. We can say that this patch is included in 10.3.6. I opened an SR to Oracle and no doubt that they are lazy as always; all they are doing is asking for lots of information but producing nothing. Btw I talked our Operation guy today and he says he forgot to restart the datasources after he disabled the "Wrapped Datatypes" utiity and he says for 3 days the GC is working fine and heap looks stabilized. I am not very sure if this is the case but it seems problem has gone. I will let you know next week.

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to guess what changes you can make in the relevant code, but based on the memory leak description - this is related to use of non thread safe hashmap.
It may help to try using ConcurrentHashMap.

Please check these links for more details:

https://support.oracle.com/knowledge/Middleware/1966075_1.html

https://javaeesupportpatterns.blogspot.com/2011/11/hashmap-thread-safe-problem-case-study.html